# Generalize many similar functions into one using varags

Tags: java, design-patterns, variadic-functions

**Background:**

I currently have a working java application that uses WorldWind to display various types of data on a world map.  The data comes from various clients via RPC. Each call is tied into a data type and has various arguments like so:

```
public synchronised ObjectID draw2DCircle(UUID userID, Position centre, Double radius){...}
public synchronised ObjectID draw2DRectangle(UUID userID, Position centre, Double width, Double length){...}
```

For every draw method there is also an update method:

```
public synchronised boolean update2DCircle(UUID userID, ObjectID objID, Position newCentre, Double newRadius).
```

Each data type has its own class so draw2DCircle has a MapSurfaceCircle class, draw2DRectangle has a MapSurfaceRectangle. There is a lot of commonality between the types and I have various interfaces for the groupings of datatypes such as 2D shapes, 3D shapes etc but the one interface that all objects have in common is the IMapObject interface that has the render, preRender, move etc calls.

The flow of operation for the draw functions is something like this:

1. Check function arguments.
2. Create MapObject.
3. Add MapObject to map layer (allows WorldWind to call render on it).
4. Update internal map that has a list of MapObjects and who owns them.
5. Return the ID of the MapObject to the caller.

The flow of operation for the update functions is something like this:

1. Check the function arguments.
2. Check that the caller owns the objects.
3. Create new *Callable* that will run the MapObjects updateXXX method.
4. Pass the callable to a *FutureTask* where it will then be fired off into the EDT.
5. Await the return via *get()* and return this back to the caller.

**The Problem:**

Normally I would not be too concerned with the setup of this but there are about 50 different types of shape that can be put on the map. That means 50 different drawXXX methods and 50 updateXXX methods each with different arguments but very similar code underneath.  I have a rather large file with lots of repetitive code which is not really that great for maintainability.

**My Thoughts:**

I need to keep the different shape type classes so will still need to have the different constructors for each one but I think I can generalize the update calls. If I remove the specific *update2DCircle*, *update2DRectagle* etc.... in the shape classes and replace with a simple update (from the base *IMapObject* interface) and use varags I should be able to funnel all the RPC update calls into one method like so:

```
update2DCircle(Args){return shape.updateShape(Args);}
update2DRectangle(Args){return shape.updateShape(Args);}
```

and each shape have the implemenation:

```
private boolean updateShape(Object ...){}
```

I understand that i'm loosing type checking with the varags but the type checking is done on the RPC implementation that made the call.

Another thought I had was to not update the shape but create a new one each time the draw/update method is called but this is slightly more complicated by the fact that the shape might be changing from internal WorldWind methods (on EDT) and the RPC methods happen on a different thread so I would need some sort of shape locking.

**Question:**

From what I have explained, does it look like any of my proposed solutions are the correct way to do it or my existing setup was OK? Is there are better solution using some design pattern i've not thought of?

*I've tried to make this as much a programming question as possible (as opposed to opinion) to meet the SO rules although I do understand how it may read but this is not my intention :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [Template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern is the one you should use

Comment: The template pattern was the solution I had mentioned in the original question (IMapObject interface with a general update method to be implemented by the shape). I guess it has two votes then;mine and yours ;)